# CSV Viewer Plugin for Jenkins

Tags: html, csv, jenkins, plugins, jenkins-plugins

I was wondering if there is any plugin for Jenkins, which can show a .csv report to an html table. Archiving an .html file seems better than archiving a .csv file in artifacts.

Thanks

Comment: did it help you? can you share a solution, please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) can help you.

Comment: I will explore it

Comment: I don't see how the HTML Publisher Plugin could show CSV content.